# How to modify the datatype of time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

The datatype in my original time series of Apache IoTDB is in "INT". Since there may be more information stored and updated to IoTDB in the future, I want to know if I want to change the datatype of this time series (for example, to "DOUBLE"), can IoTDB modify the datatype? If the datatype can be switched, how should I change it?

Does any one can deal this problem？Help please

Answer (score 0):

Switching the datatype from "INT" to "DOUBLE" can be done in Apache IoTDB by first renaming another time series using "select into" (at this point you can specify a compatible new datatype), deleting the original time series, and then changing the name of the new time series to the old name that you are familiar with.

At present, other datatypes cannot be directly modified, and altering other datatypes will be able to execute in the future versions.